# Get ID name of a clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems like it should be so simple but for some reason I can't get it working. I want to get the id of a clicked element.

The element:

```
<i id="fav6" onclick="changefave()" style="color: #DDD;" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
```

The js:

```
function changefave(){
alert(this.id);
}
```

It's current returning, 'Undefined'.

Note: the element id is generated dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: `changefave.call(this)`. What's the reason for using inline event handlers if you have jQuery available?

Comment: It should be `<i id="fav6" onclick="changefave(this)" style="color: #DDD;" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>` and `function chagefave(control){alert(control.id);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `onclick` attribute of the `<i>` tag like:-

```
onclick="changefave(this);"
```

and the function like:

```
function changefave(obj) {
    alert(obj.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yoy can try this

```
function changefave(obj) {
   alert(obj.id);
}
```

HTML

```
<i id="fav6" onclick="changefave(this)" style="color: #DDD;" class="fa fa-star-o">something</i>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6uruH/)

Answer (score 0):

in html

```
<i id="fav6" onclick="changefave(this)" style="color: #DDD;" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
```

**in js**

```
function changefave(this){
alert(this.id);
}
```

or by **jQuery** you can do

in html remove **inline onclick**

```
 <i id="fav6"  style="color: #DDD;" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
```

and  script will

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#fav6").click(function(){
alert($(this).attr("id");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better not to do inline JavaScript.  So, your HTML should be

```
<i id="fav6" style="color: #DDD;" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
```

Then, in JavaScript:

```
$(function() { // waits for document and jQuery to load
    $('#fav6').on('click', function() {
        alert( $(this).prop('id') );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

**HTML CODE**

```
        <i id="fav6" onclick="changefave(this);" style="color: #DDD;" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
        function changefave(obj){
            alert(obj.id);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it along with the "this" pointer as argument in the function call .

`Hence your code in html should be`

```
<i id="fav6" onclick="changefave(this)" style="color: #DDD;" class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
```

`And the javascript function should be`

```
function changefave(ele)
{
    // here ele refers to the called element 
    alert(ele.id);
}
```

`Refer to this link to know more about 'this'` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this